# Is it possible by any way I can override the equals/compare to method of Integer and String classes?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

To customise ordering of elements in `TreeSet` I have to do following

1. Implement the comparable interface
2. Override compareTo method in that element’s class

Similarly is there any way where I can do the same to the `String` class and `Integer` class?

Comment: No you don't. You can provide a `Comparator` instead. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` receives a `Comparator` so you can define a different compare method, for example I want to sort strings based on their second character

```
TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.substring(1, 2)));
treeSet.add("avec");
treeSet.add("ipsum");
treeSet.add("lorem");
```

will print

```
[lorem, ipsum, avec]
```

Comment: To compare by the second character, `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.charAt(1))` would be preferable.